# getJSON inside a function causing an infinite loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, infinite-loop

I'm working on a Codeigniter application and in a page I'm using jQuery to make an Ajax call to a function inside a controller. I pass to this function some values taken from the page; the function make some calculations and then I have to display the result. All of this withouth refreshing the page.

The ajax code is this:

```
$.getJSON("photos/change_product", {product_id: product_type, ajax: 'true'}, function(data) {
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        options.push('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].label + '</option>');
    }
    $("select#options").html(options.join(''));
    })
};
```

When I trigger it from a click event on some html element it works just fine. The problem is that I also need it to run when I load the page the first time. So I thought I could move that code into a function and then call it wherever I needed it. So, I created a changeProduct function with the code above and then called it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function changeProduct(product_type) {

    $.getJSON("photos/change_product", {product_id: product_type, ajax: 'true'}, function(data) {
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        options.push('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].label + '</option>');
    }
    $("select#options").html(options.join(''));
    })
};

var selected_product = $("ul#products li:first-child a");
changeProduct(selected_product);
```

And this is causing an infinite loop of page refreshing. How can I avoid this? Shall I create counters and conditionals or is there some better way?

SOLVED: the problem is in the selected_product variable. It should be something like this:

```
var selected_product = $("ul#products li:first-child a").val();
```

Comment: What happens if you move the function out of the document.ready but make the call to the function in the document.ready instead?

Comment: I've already tried. It happens the same thing. The problem it's the call.

Comment: Strange because all you're doing is creating an array, joining it and inserting it into the select tag! You don't have any javascript errors in your console do you? Try persisting the console - it might be hitting the page, erroring and refreshing somehow

Comment: do you use firebug or similar debug tool ? this could help you determine where is the pb

Comment: from jquery site : mportant: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

Comment: You will probably find the request is failing/throwing an error possibly causing a page refresh - effectively starting the whole thing over again

Comment: ok, I'm getting this error: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMLocation.replace]
http://localhost/~carlo/website/assets/js/jquery.js
Line 7449

Comment: Is this all of the javascript code in your file? Maybe have a look over here - http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/151127-add-item-select-ie-but-not-mozilla

Comment: ok, this really seems to be the problem. Changing the code to this:

 $.getJSON("photos/change_product", {"product_id": "product_type", "ajax": "true"}, function(data) {

made it work.

Comment: is it because 'selected_product' is a jquery object? Do you want to do something like $("ul#products li:first-child a").text() instead?

Comment: well, actually, this stopped the loop, but this way I'm just passing product_type as a string, while I need its value. so something's still wrong

Comment: yes, I've just found out. sorry this was kind of stupid, but I was going crazy

Comment: No worries at all ;) Feel free to give me an up vote if anything I said was remotely helpful!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5442/discussion-between-carlo-and-jamie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because 'selected_product' is a jquery object? Do you want to do something like $("ul#products li:first-child a").text() instead to get it's value?